# How do I show separation and clear diamonds?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

So I've been having a lot of trouble with this project. I want to make a diamond pile falling animation but the diamonds are pixelated and when I render a frame of the animation it is not that clear that they're diamonds.

I use the NLM denoiser (because it seems to be better than OptiX)
I already tried increasing my resolution from 1080p to 1440p (doesn't seem to do much)
I use 512 samples per pixel
32 light paths

[image: Blender screenshot]

[image: Diamond shader]

[image: Diamond singular]

[image: Diamond pile]

It seems like I am missing some totally obvious settings. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: try disabling denoiser. the image has too "random" noise for the denoiser to make the image clear.

Comment: I’d say one of the things about diamonds that isn’t showing up here is how bright the refracted light is, and how often it’s a different color. Are you sure your varying the refraction indexes of the colors enough? Why do you add in a white shader afterwards? If that is all correct, I might add a glare node to the compositor.

Comment: I think you're getting a pretty realistic result, looking at reference it's pretty hard to pick out edges.  More glossy bounces!  It is usually internal glossy bounces that hit the limit and come back as pure black.